# How do I install and use WinPcap?

Tags: windows, pcap, winpcap

I went to winpcap.org today, downloaded the installer, and installed WinPcap on my Windows 7 laptop PC. However, the folder where it was installed contains only an installation log, an executable called rpcapd.exe, and an uninstall executable. When I run rpcapd.exe a dos shell appears:

```
Press CTLR+C to stop the server...
```

and nothing happens until I press CTRL+C, which closes the window. When I create a project in Microsoft Visual Studio and include < pcap.h >, I'm told there is no such file or directory. A search of my computer yields no results. I've tried reinstalling a couple times but with no new results. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Development with WinPcap requires both the driver install, as well as the developer's pack.  Have you installed the [developer's pack](http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm)?