# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pcap.h'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pcap.h': No such file or
>   directory.

How to add `.pcap.h` file? I am doing VC++ project in windows 7 32-bit

Comment: Does pcap.h exist on your computer?  If so add it's directory to the projects include path.

Comment: i added the file but still include file showing some errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8978802/560648

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download winpcap developer pack from [here](http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm) and follow the instructions on that page. [Here](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcapsamps.html) are the additional details on adding include paths and linker paths.

> 1.download the ZIP archive containing the developer's pack 
>   2.uncompress it to the desired folder

Comment: thanks..... what can i do to get RTP packets from saved .pcap file by a cpp program